# PHP - populate a multidimensional associative array using values from input form

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

As above, I'm trying to populate an array from an html input form but I'm getting a little confused

A: I think I have declared the array correctly, but where should I declare it so that each time the form is submitted, a new record is created rather than a new array declared?
B: How do I correctly reference the sub-array to populate the student details under the else statement?

My code is below

```
<body>
    <?php
        //Create variables from user input
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $address=$_POST['address'];
        $major=$_POST['major'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];

        //Create associative array
        $students = array('name'=> array(''), 
                          'id' => array(''),
                          'address' => array(''),
                          'major' => array(''),
                          'email' => array(''),
                          'phone' => array('')
                          );

        //Error checking
        if(!$name || !$id || !$address || !$major || !$email || !$phone){
             echo '<p align="center">
                    At least one input entry is missing, <br/>
                    please go back and try again.
                </p>';
             echo '<p align="center"><a href="task1.html">Back to Selection</a></p>';
        }//end if
        else{
            //populate students array with values entered
            $students['name'] = $name;
            $students['id'] = $id;
            $students['address'] = $address;
            $students['major'] = $major;
            $students['email'] = $email;
            $students['phone'] = $phone;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you can add a new dataset to `$students` every time the form is sent in a way you're trying it now.
The problem: If you submit the form, an entirely new page will be called, while the data from the previous page is basically gone. You somehow need to work around that.

Here are some options, starting with the most stupid one.

**Option 1**
Use JS. On a submit, not a new page is called but a JS-script collects the data and stores it into the array. Disadvantes: Needs JS, Data will be lost once page is reloaded.

**Option 2**
Use server-side variables like `$SESSION` or `$SERVER`. Those are arrays that can store data. They exist not on the user's device but on your web server. That way, data can be kept over multiple called web pages. Usually, as long as you either delete it yourself or when the user closes the browser. You could make a new record to them every time the form is submitted. Disadvantage: Data gone as soon as variable is reset (however this happens).

**Option 3 (recommended)**
Use a database. I don't know the purpose of your array, but usually you want to save those information for longer than when the browser is closed. The form submission passes the data via `$_POST` to a new PHP-File which creates a connection to a database on your server and fills in the data. Later, when needed, you can get the data as array from this database.